# Multitenant grails plugin - grails.plugin.multitenant.core.exception.NoCurrentTenantException

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-plugin, multi-tenant

Grails giving this error when i saved an instance which is associated with @multitenant annotation but no tenant is present there. So i explicitly try to put tenant id by using

```
objInstance.setTenantId(tenantId)
```

throws this exception :

```
grails.plugin.multitenant.core.exception.NoCurrentTenantException: Tried to save multi-tenant domain class 'objInstance', but no tenant is set
```

When i use

```
Customer.withTenantId(tenantId){ objInstance.save(flush:true) }
```

then it throws this exception :

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions
```

CONTROLLER CODE :

```
def myservice
def myAction(MOrder objInstance1){
 objInstance1.properties = params;
 objInstance1?.save(flush:true)
 myservice.callingMyserviceMEthod(objInstance1)
}
```

Service Code:

```
def callingMyserviceMEthod(MOrder objInstance1){
   objInstance1.setOrderProcess(true);
   objInstance1?.save(flush:true);

if(objInstance1.getOrderProcess()){
    // creating new object object of POrder as objInstance1
    POrder objInstance = new POrder();
    objInstance?.setName("ABC");
    objInstance?.setOrderStatus("process");
    objInstance?.setTenantId(objInstance1?.getTenantId());
    objInstance?.save(flush:true);

    // I also tried this code with Customer.withTenantId()
    /*
    Customer.withTenantId(){
        POrder objInstance = new POrder();
        objInstance?.setName("ABC");
        objInstance?.setOrderStatus("process");

        objInstance?.save(flush:true);

      } */

   }
}
```

Do not understand how to save that objInsatance ?????

Comment: `withTenantId` working fine at my end. If your domain have other domains then create your object inside `withTenantId` closure.

Comment: flow is like that my controller's action gets call and in this controller we are saving a domain say "objIntance1" now i want to create and save a new instace of other domain class say "objInstance" with same tenant id of objInstace1 and when i mark save objInstace it gives error. org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: yes i have paste sample code with question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use merge instead of save. objInstance?.merge();

Comment: solved my problem by using merge() instead using save()